# Github in Rstudio giving 'The directory name is invalid'

Tags: github, rstudio

I have a github repository that I want to connect to Rstudio. I can clone the repository without problem using the `new project` button and using the version control, but then cannot pull, push, diff, or look at history.

To be more specific: When I click on **any** of the actions related to version control from within Rstudio I get a pop-up error window with the message 'The directory name is invalid', with only an 'OK' button. Pressing OK closes the error message and also the related window for history, push, etc.

The directory name and the repository name do not have any non-ascii characters. I am using Rstudio version 0.99.486 on windows 7.

This is not a problem with git, since I can pull, push and diff from the command-line without any errors.

I should probably mention that I am not using the public github repository but a business github.

A similar question (39698320) was asked without an answer.

Comment: Can you please be more clear? Exactly what action are you attempting to take in RStudio, and what error message is being reported? (Screenshots would be helpful)

Comment: Sure, I will be more explicit - edited the question to be more specific.